# asp.net requiredfieldvalidators, why are they not firing when i have OnClientClick implemented

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have some requiredfieldvalidators.

when i have a regular asp:button, all goes well.

But, now we've implemented the OnClientClick event on the submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save changes" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" OnClientClick="return SubmitForm2();" />
```

the submitform2 method is implemented to set the caption of the submitbutton (please wait) and to disable it to avoid double clicking.

```
  function SubmitForm2() {
        $("#SaveButton").attr("disabled", "true");
        $("#SaveButton").val("Please wait...");

        __doPostBack("SaveButton", "");
        return true;

    }
```

but what we see is when we run this code, the clientsidevalidators are not called.

is that because we run the `__doPostBack` ourselves, that otherwise other code (to check the validators) is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - post-back is happening because you are doing `__doPostBack` by yourself. Once you disable the button, submit behavior by the button gets supressed blocking validators.

One of better implementation of desired functionality could be to set the js-timer for short duration for disabling button and then for longer duration for enabling the button. For example,

```
function SubmitForm2() {
        // disable button after 30 ms
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#SaveButton").attr("disabled", "true");
            $("#SaveButton").val("Please wait...");

            // enable button in 15 seconds so that in case validations are 
            // failed, user can correct and re-submit the page.
            setTimeout(function() {
               $("#SaveButton").removeAttr("disabled");
               $("#SaveButton").val("Save");
            }, 15000); 

        }, 30);

        return true;
    }
```

Even better implementation can be achieved by using [validator's client side API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside). Here's one such simpler but better modification of previous one,

```
function SubmitForm2() {
            // disable button after 30 ms
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#SaveButton").attr("disabled", "true");
                $("#SaveButton").val("Please wait...");

                // enable button in 1 second in case validations are 
                // failed, user can correct and re-submit the page.
                setTimeout(function() {
                   if (!Page_IsValid) {
                      // validations failed
                      $("#SaveButton").removeAttr("disabled");
                      $("#SaveButton").val("Save");
                   }
                }, 1000); 

            }, 30);

            return true;
        }
```